# Springboot 1.5.10: Enable Actuator Health URL without cert authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spring-boot-actuator

Springboot 1.5.10: Enable Actuator Health URL without cert authentication

My application requires X509 client certificate authentication to consume the rest service, however am trying to enable actuator `/health` endpoint without client certificate authentication

Below is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
        springVersion = '4.3.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()        
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7.1"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}"
    compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10"
    compile "com.microsoft:sqljdbc4:4.0"
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile "jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17"
}
```

Below is the config class I created to bypass lient certificate authentication for actuator `/health` endpoint

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthenticationService extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()

    }
    @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector")
    public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() {
        return new HandlerMappingIntrospector();
    }       
}
```

below is my yaml config

```
server:   
  ssl:
    client-auth: need
management:
  health:
    defaults:
      enabled: false
```

The above code compiling fine but am getting the below error when I start the applicatoin, can someone help to fix this error?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in com.abc.SBApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector]: Factory method 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ListableBeanFactory must not be null
```